# Unable to start MySQL server in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

**I run this command**

```
service mysqld status
```

**It show this**

```
● mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

when i run this command to start sql server

```
sudo service mysql start
```

**It show this**

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are different database engines, the commands suggest you are trying to use MySQL but your comments contradict this.

Comment: okay i want to start mysql server.

Comment: when  i try to open my database in phpmyadmin it show this error; #2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: @Vipin Farswan you need to tag this question with `ubuntu` & `sql-server`.

Comment: Or rather untag SQL Server - since you specified in the comment you are using MySQL.

Comment: Seems to be 100's of answers to this question when googled, many on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - this question does not look related to PHP after all

Comment: i also try service mysql status. it show mysql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: @NicoHaase I removed the php tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found solution of this.

1. First i copy the database frm files for backup.
2. Then i removed sql server completely.
3. Then i install sql server again.
4. after that i copy the frm files and paste in /var/lib/mysql
5. run command sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql.
6. And last restart the sql server with sudo service mysql restart